# Principle of superposition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

[image]

Here $\phi$ is the solution to a linear pde so the principle of superposition applies. $\theta$ is the phase.

I've tried using trig identities and different linear combinations in order to try and get the expression for $\phi$, but I haven't made any progress. How can I proceed?

Comment: The writing is hard to read. Could you enter it in text, or at least show a graphic of better writing?

Comment: What do you actually want to know, too?

Comment: I think he or she is looking for how to take a linear combination of the terms in the bracket and apply trig to derive $A\cos(kx \pm wt + \theta)$.

Comment: @Chappers zahbaz is correct

Answer (score 0):

The cheap way is to expand out the thing you want:
$$ \cos{(kx \pm \omega t + \theta)} = \cos{(kx \pm \omega t)}\cos{\theta}-\sin{(kx \pm \omega t)}\sin{\theta} \\
= (\cos{kx}\cos{\omega t}\mp \sin{kx} \sin{\omega t})\cos{\theta} -(\sin{kx}\cos{\omega t} \pm \cos{kt} \sin{\omega t})\sin{\theta} $$
(Of course, actually deriving it just means going the other way.)

Comment: Why are we able to introduce $cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$? (When going the other way)

Comment: Since you are meant to start with a linear combination, you can choose any coefficients you like for your four functions. It so happens that these are the right ones (it's like the factorisation $A\cos{x}+B\sin{x}=C\cos{(x-t)}$: you prove that you can choose the values of $C$ and $t$ such that it works, by expanding the right-hand side.